# Install ASP.NET MVC4 framework affected performance of MVC3 site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

We have a Win 2008 web server running an ASP.NET MVC3 website.

In **preparation** to upgrading the site to MVC4, the MVC4 framework was installed on the server:

1. Install .NET 4.5 framework
2. Install .NET 4.5 patches
3. Install ASP.MVC 4 framework

After that our MVC3 site is now running extremely slowly (many seconds to respond).  Other websites (whose AppPools use v2.0 of the framework) are running just fine, but not this one that's running v4.0.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Griff

Comment: We checked **everything** (more or less) and found no explanation.  The next time we did a code roll, this fixed the problem.  One thing we didn't do was to manually delete the temporary ASP.NET files and this may have been the cause of the problem (the temporary internet files were created with the 4.0 framework but the IIS was running the 4.5 "flavour" of the .NET framework).  Sadly I'll never know, but if it happens again then these files will be the first things to go.

Comment: Have you had this problem again or is the cause still a mystery? We are experiencing a similar issue and are grasping at straws at this point.